# Added celery to admin group, but still can't run the bash script

Tags: debian, permissions

I'm logged in as celery,

```
celery@de-vpn-2:/etc/app$ ls -lt
total 8
-rwx------ 1 admin admin 144 Jun 12 18:39 user-count.sh
```

But I have no permission running the bash script:

```
celery@de-vpn-2:/etc/app$ bash user-count.sh
bash: user-count.sh: Permission denied
```

However I'm added to admin group

```
sudo usermod -a -G admin celery
```

So why don't I have permission to run it?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group doesn't have any access to the file.

If you want the celery user to be able to execute the file:

```
chmod g+rx user-count.sh
```

That adds read and execute permissions to the file for the admin group. After that, start a new shell session with celery and the user can execute the file.